# Unable to create instance with Excel.Application

Tags: c#, excel, object

I'm creating a console app that randomly picks questions and answers from an Excel file. Below is my code (not at all complete).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace QuizMaker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numCorrectA;
            int numTotalQ;
            decimal score;
            List<string> qArray = new List<string>();
            List<string> aArray = new List<string>();

            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook quizWorkbook = new xlApp.Workbooks.Open("-file location-");

            //read random line from excel file for 6 questions

            //print out questions

            //console.readline() for the answers

            //check answers b ycomparing them

            //increment ints as needed

            //output results


        }
    }
}
```

So I created `xlApp` by calling the `Application` interface, but when I go to use`xlApp` in the line below, I get hit with a "is a variable but used like a type" error. After looking it up it seems that interfaces don't create instances, so that would be why. However, I've tried to create another class to implement Excel.Application, and that didn't work. I don't understand what else I need to do in order for me to create a new application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

> Excel.Workbook quizWorkbook = new xlApp.Workbooks.Open("-file
>   location-");

Remove the `new` keyword, because this is the thing that is trying to create an instance from `xlApp`. As it is said in the error - your `xlApp` is a variable, not a type from which you have to create an object.

The return value of `xlApp.Workbooks.Open("-file location-");` will be `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook`.

Some more [info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx).

And info about the differences between variables and types - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables). More or less the *variable* is an object of *type*.

Answer (score 0):

`Excel.Application` is a static library. Remove the `new` from your statement opening the workbook.

As an aside, you might want to look into using EPPlus.  It's a great library for working with Excel files.  You can get it from nuget.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
Excel.Workbook quizWorkbook = new xlApp.Workbooks.Open("-file location-");
```

You call method `Open` with `new` operator. So you essentially trying to create instance of the class `new Open()` which is not valid. You should just use

```
Excel.Workbook quizWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("-file location-");
```

The reason why it even compiles, is that [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) treats [com](/questions/tagged/com) interfaces as [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic) types, that evaluates on runtime, and compiler does not know what it is during the compilation.